# Animate and fade in, simultaneously, on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, toggle, fade

Here's what I have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("on"); 
      $("#m_1").fadeToggle(150);
    });
</script>
```

It is a menu that fades in on click.  I would like it to go from `margin-top: -80px;` to `margin-top:80px` when it is clicked "on", but vice versa when it is clicked "off", all with the slow fade.

I'm not too experienced with coding, so I am sorry if this seems juvenile.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You can run the different animation depending on the state of the `on` class

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  //run the stop to make sure the animation isnt already running
  $(this).stop(true, true)
  //fire the animation based on the class state
  if ($(this).hasClass('on')) $(this).animate({margin-top : '80px'});
  else $(this).animate({margin-top : '-80px'});

  //toggle the class
  $(this).toggleClass("on"); 

  $("#m_1").fadeToggle(150);
});
```

You can add the opacity toggle to the .animate call as well if you would like. depends on what `$("#m_1").fadeToggle(150);` is doing